# Need help to convert this piece of code in codeigniter

Tags: sql, codeigniter

Can anyone help me convert this?

```
SELECT  id,ospos_people.first_name,ospos_people.last_name,customer_id,is_draft 
from
(SELECT  
          ospos_quotations.id,
          ospos_quotations.customer_id, 
          ospos_quotations.is_draft,
          ospos_quotations.date 
 from     ospos_quotations, ospos_quotation_items
 where  ospos_quotations.id= ospos_quotation_items.quotation_id 
 and ospos_quotation_items.line=1) AS T 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ospos_people on T.customer_id = ospos_people.person_id
```

Comment: Whoever migrated didn't seem to know what kind of questions we like here..

Comment: simply use above query in $this-db->query(your_above query)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have converted your query to be more optimized like this

```
SELECT
  id,
  ospos_people.first_name,
  ospos_people.last_name,
  customer_id,
  is_draft
from (SELECT
    ospos_quotations.id,
    ospos_quotations.customer_id,
    ospos_quotations.is_draft,
    ospos_quotations.date
      from ospos_quotations
    LEFT JOIN ospos_quotation_items
      ON ospos_quotations.id = ospos_quotation_items.quotation_id
      where ospos_quotation_items.line = 1) AS T
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ospos_people
    on T.customer_id = ospos_people.person_id
```

In this inner query i have used join instead of FROM table1, table2

You can convert the query like this

You can use sub query way of codeigniter to do this for this 
purpose you will have to hack codeigniter. like this. Go to 
system/database/DB_active_rec.php Remove public or protected 
keyword from these functions

```
public function _compile_select($select_override = FALSE)
public function _reset_select()
```

Now subquery writing in available And now here is your query with active record

```
function myquery()
{
    $select =   array(
                    'ospos_quotations.id',
                    'ospos_quotations.customer_id', 
                    'ospos_quotations.is_draft',
                    'ospos_quotations.date'
                );
    $this->db->select($select);
    $this->db->from('ospos_quotations');
    $this->db->join('ospos_quotation_items','ospos_quotations.id= ospos_quotation_items.quotation_id ','left');
    $this->db->where('ospos_quotation_items.line',1);
    $subQuery = $this->db->_compile_select(); // get query string

    $this->db->_reset_select(); // reset the object to write new query

    unset($select);

    $select =   array(
                    'id',
                    'ospos_people.first_name',
                    'ospos_people.last_name',
                    'customer_id,is_draft' 
                );
    $this->db->select($select);             
    $this->db->from("($subQuery) AS T");
    $this->db->join('ospos_people','T.customer_id = ospos_people.person_id ','left outer');
    return $this->db->get()->result();
}
```

And the thing is done. Cheers!!!
Note : While using sub queries you must use

```
$this->db->from('table_name')
```

instead of

```
$this->db->get('table_name')
```

which runs the query.

EDITS :

Here is an alternative way. Simply use `$this->db->query($query)` function

```
function myquery()
{
    $query  =   "   SELECT
                      id,
                      ospos_people.first_name,
                      ospos_people.last_name,
                      customer_id,
                      is_draft
                    from (SELECT
                        ospos_quotations.id,
                        ospos_quotations.customer_id,
                        ospos_quotations.is_draft,
                        ospos_quotations.date
                          from ospos_quotations
                        LEFT JOIN ospos_quotation_items
                          ON ospos_quotations.id = ospos_quotation_items.quotation_id
                          where ospos_quotation_items.line = 1) AS T
                      LEFT OUTER JOIN ospos_people
                        on T.customer_id = ospos_people.person_id";
    return $this->db->query($query)->result();  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe:

```
$sql = 'SELECT  id,ospos_people.first_name,ospos_people.last_name,customer_id,is_draft 
from
(SELECT  
          ospos_quotations.id,
          ospos_quotations.customer_id, 
          ospos_quotations.is_draft,
          ospos_quotations.date 
 from     ospos_quotations, ospos_quotation_items
 where  ospos_quotations.id= ospos_quotation_items.quotation_id 
 and ospos_quotation_items.line=1) AS T 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ospos_people on T.customer_id = ospos_people.person_id';

$this->db->query($sql);


// OR 

$this->db
    ->select('id,ospos_people.first_name,ospos_people.last_name,customer_id,is_draft')
    ->from('(SELECT  
          ospos_quotations.id,
          ospos_quotations.customer_id, 
          ospos_quotations.is_draft,
          ospos_quotations.date 
 from     ospos_quotations, ospos_quotation_items
 where  ospos_quotations.id= ospos_quotation_items.quotation_id 
 and ospos_quotation_items.line=1) AS T', false)
    ->join('ospos_people', 'T.customer_id = ospos_people.person_id', 'left outer');
```